# Resolving dependency conflict for npm install in Angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies

I had several error messages for overriding peer dependencies when doing an npm install. After following the steps proposed by the accepted solution to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773818/npm-dependency-conflict). The most essential part being **change the ~ versions to ^, remove node_modules and (if it exists) package-lock.json and run npm install again**. I have now reduced the error message to the following :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: console@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: tslib@2.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/tslib
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.0.0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^10.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=9.0.0" from mat-table-exporter@9.1.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/mat-table-exporter
npm ERR!       mat-table-exporter@"^9.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@angular/material)
npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/common, @angular/core, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from mat-table-exporter@9.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/mat-table-exporter
npm ERR!   mat-table-exporter@"^9.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /my/path/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /my/path/.npm/_logs/2022-07-21T15_27_07_820Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I solve this dependency issue? I cannot simply use --force or --legacy-peer-deps because my next step afterwards is moving from Angular 10 to 13. I tried doing the upgrade without fixing this issue and it forces @angular/cdk to remain at 10.x.x

Comment: I guess mat-table-exporter is too old? Maybe there are newer versions available?

Comment: You are correct, the mat-table-exporter we had was for angular 9. I went to https://www.npmpeer.dev/packages/mat-table-exporter/compatibility and updated the version to the latest compatible version with angular 10. Thanks!